# Swift - custom Decoder has no decode() function

Tags: swift, decoder

I've created a custom `Decoder` that decodes a very specific data format, following [this tutorial](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E115-building-a-custom-xml-decoder).

*Please note, my data format is not XML or JSON.*

I started with:

```
public final class MyDecoder: Decoder {
    public var codingPath: [CodingKey] = []
    public var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey:Any] = [:]
    public let input: String
    
    public init(_ input: String) {
        self.input = input
    }

    // all stubs are below
```

And added all the stubs needed for the protocol. Then, following the video, I also added a struct that conforms to `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol`, and filled out the required parsing in `decode(_ type: String.Type, forKey key: Key)`.

To get the info out, I do this:

```
let decoder = MyDecoder(input)
let info = try! myRecord(from: decoder)
```

So far so good this works.

What I want to do next is to see if it is possible to do this like is done for a `JSONDecoder`:

```
let decoder = MyDecoder()
guard let info = try? decoder.decode(MyInfo.self, from: input) else {
   fatalError("Failed to decode data")
}
```

But of course that doesn't work, because `MyDecoder` doesn't have a `decode()` function.

So, my question is, if I add this function, what should go in it?

Comment: You can take a look at [the implementation of `JSONDecoder`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L1038) to get a better sense of how this works, but in general, the type you write which conforms to `Decoder` is usually _not_ the top-level type which implements `decode(_:from:)`. `Decoder` is used at the "middle" and "bottom" levels of decoding but the top-level interface is different. `JSONDecoder` uses a private `_JSONDecoder` class as its actual `Decoder` instance.

Comment: In other words, the tutorial gives you a working `Decoder` implementation, but you'll likely want to wrap it in another type to give a different API surface which is _not_ accessible during an actual `init(from:)`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/topleveldecoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on the very useful comments, I changed my code as follows. First I added a top level `MyDecoder` struct, and changed the name of the original decoder to `_MyDecoder`.

```
public struct MyDecoder: TopLevelDecoder, Decodable {
    public typealias Input = String

    public init() {}

    public func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from input: String) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        let decoder = _MyDecoder(input)
        
        return try! MyRecord(from: decoder) as! T
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, this also works without using the `TopLevelDecoder` protocol (and thus can run on < iOS 13):

```
//...

public func decode<T : Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T {
   let decoder = _MyDecoder(input)
        
   return try! MyRecord(from: decoder) as! T
}
```

And now I can call the decoder as follows:

```
let decoder = MyDecoder()
return try! decoder.decode(MyRecord.self, from: input)
```